# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Я написал утилиту, которая преобразует массив в объект объектов. Но компилятор TS выдает непонятную ошибку

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature of type 'string' was found on type '{}'`

Вот сам код:

```
type Map<V> = { [key: string]: V };

export const arrayToObjectByKey = (
  arr: Array<object>,
  keyField: string = 'id',
): Map<object> =>
  Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(item => ({ [item[keyField]]: item })));
```

Ругается на строке `{ [item[keyField]]: item }`
Как это исправить и вообще почему это происходит?

Comment: поменяйте Array<object> на Array<any>. Array<object> не имеет свойств которые вы пытаетесь ему присвоить (он пустой)

Comment: да там куча всего, тот же `Map` зарезервированный тип. не ясно что автор хочет. заткнуть линтер, послушать лекцию, или написать хитрый дженерик

Comment: @RTW я не хочу использовать `any`,  хочу написать тогда хитрый generic, как выше написано.

Comment: ```export const arrayToObjectByKey = <T>(
  arr: Array<T>,
  keyField: string = 'id',
): Map<T>```

Comment: и это тоже не спасает ситуацию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

не спрашивайте у меня зечем это автору
не спрашивайте у меня зечем это сообществу
я просто оставлю тут

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?alwaysStrict=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=22&ssc=25&pln=22&pc=46#code/PQKhCgAIUwmEEwgiCG4QQwiCHEQQDCCFYQSh%20EEHwggvCCAcIIDwgGJg8iCT6CMIIFIgWgXCCBCIPvMZE0oHIgaWgThBIkKDE5o2iFhSwtENBszalIWZJyyBmEHyRiCAkkAyIIHYQdhhaGuGJl15oAXKMgADV1GEAXAJ4AHAKaQACQA1n5ekAC8kACGAHZeANzuLm7CiKT4LIACIJy0SPg2zgAqAEzOosDg3v5BoeFRsQCuALYARn4ATpAAPpAAzh4dAJaxAOY9-V5tAPYANknAwJAAtAA0y%20AjHp0AZtEAxgGBQ9vNkADeyZAA2sH2-YMjowC69yFhSQC%204Isr61W%20I7NaI%20AA8RQAfJELjc7g9hmNXpAipBvr81htqkdoh0OtEvEVpgB5VoAKz8%20w8ACEvABpMLQ8GQPwAD22sQAJn0gic-M1VpBacy2X5Ody6tMdsiIQAKK44jr3ACCuPx4IhArqADEhn5Zhz7rTVuAAJSRKGBYFgyELJYY8DgfbTWIDGKqgnEskU6l0sJvBX4wkk8mUmn0%20qQGWzIYDACSp01YXjfLNEQhV2D3quaUgADpon0%20kNRrE5Tny2lM5Tc-sOn5otsZU1ZrMTcaKxXc13o3HTrmrTLeWc05Hsx2c5dx1O0tcx9Px0PbknTs85-PhEih2vx991yaTWuTba-hsigBGe6TtLo-45p0ujyTGYAGWhAGUpq05jKj1d766FWha4AHJomAgVgNaYDniSO9nVdABHBDoQDD0qx9cMyw7Wd13OSBgKGDlgPuYCkIQ4DUXbec8IIoj7j6T9plfT4qOnGjCOIyAzzPSjtzSdi6LdLoWMgX4ikBABRXFpg6NdnggjjfxzG8Njgl05j8XMOSGDoZSQg9lLtW80n-DTc1maZRhlUikIoiJ7MgJDczI3NCKUkz4LMiyrIYl9IgcpDrl8r9n2eVyOXc4RTNmTTvJlbj-KiQLuLCtzYLSBVLzXaLYssmVAPspKEOuBVUoi9KKxy8y8oKgLipAsCIKg54ysi8sqri2qioa1ZmvC38rm%20T5j3tUossMk8-3gx8CpuUDwPw5qKsgf9HyQlD3SDL1Q19LwsIrHDqPwjj7kAkSxMk6TZPHeTjqItqVKm9SYq0nS9IQgzryM1SPOe3KrK6xzitK-rlo6mrcUSoHrgahbIOg1qwc8l7OshwrodA3roNB8BhqAA)

### TS

````
/**
 * в случае понимания объектов и ключей  
 * и что станет с объектом если его использовать как ключ:
 * ```
   type $key = any;
   ```
   смотри блок `T2`
 */
type $key = number | string | symbol;
// -,-
interface $item {
    [k: string]: $key;
}
// -,-
type $map<T> = { [k: string]: T }
// -,-
type $arrayToObjectByKey = <T extends $item, K extends keyof T>(
    arr: Array<T>, keyField: K,
) => $map<T>;
// -,-

const arrayToObjectByKey: $arrayToObjectByKey = (listItem, keyItem) =>
    Object
        .assign(
            Object.create(null),
            ...listItem.map(item => (
                {
                    [
                        item[keyItem]
                    ]: item
                }
            ))
        );
````

### JS

```js
const arrayToObjectByKey = (listItem, keyItem) => Object.assign(Object.create(null), ...listItem.map(item => ({
  [item[keyItem]]: item
})));
// -,-
T1: {
  // -,-
  const symboL = Symbol();
  const arr = ['a', 'b'];
  const qq = arrayToObjectByKey(
      [
          { 'id': 'qqq' },
          { 'id': symboL },
          { 'id': 11 },
          { 'id': arr }, // TypeError
      ], 'id');
  // -,-
  // console.dir(qq)
  // -,-
  console.log('qqq' === qq.qqq.id);
  console.log(symboL === qq[symboL].id);
  console.log(11 === qq[11].id);
  arr: {
    console.log(arr === qq[arr].id);
    console.log(arr === qq[['a', 'b']].id);
    console.log(arr === qq['a,b'].id);

  }
};
```

```js
const arrayToObjectByKey = (listItem, keyItem) => Object.assign(Object.create(null), ...listItem.map(item => ({
  [item[keyItem]]: item
})));
// -,-
T2: {
  // -,-
  const arr = ['a', 'b'];
  const qq = arrayToObjectByKey(
    [{
        'id': arr
      }, // TypeError
    ], 'id');
  // -,-
  // console.dir(qq)
  // -,-
  console.log(arr === qq[arr].id);
  console.log(arr === qq[['a', 'b']].id);
  console.log(arr === qq['a,b'].id);
};
```